# Associative array dynamic key addition error

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, csv

I am converting a CSV to JSON object to render data in a html table. When creating object I am using associative array to create a key,value pair structure of the object, but last column of the CSV file is becoming inaccessible because it is creating object as follows,

Object {code:"F1",description:"Family 1",discount: "0.2","validity":"1434567098"}

So I can't access data for "validity" in my code. It is only happening with the last column of CSV file. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Please refer to this block of code,

```
reader.onload = function(e) {
                var fileData = e.target.result.split("\n"),
                    tableData = [],
                    tData = {},
                    length = fileData.length;
                for(i=0;i<length;i++){
                  csvObj.push(fileData[i]);
                }
                theaderArray = csvObj[0].toLowerCase().split(",");
                for(k=1;k<csvObj.length;k++){
                  tData = {};
                  csvDataArray = csvObj[k].split(",");
                  if(csvDataArray[0]){
                    angular.forEach(theaderArray, function(val,key){
                      tData[val] = csvDataArray[key];
                    });
                  }
                    tableData.push(tData);
                }
                $rootScope.familyList = tableData;
           }
```

Comment: i dont see a problem, please paste code that creates the object

Comment: maybe you have an invisible char in the col name, i don't see why else that one would get quotes and the others would not.

Comment: tData[val] is the associative array I am refering to,@dandavis chrome debugger doesn't show any thing else than string "validity" while debugging, I am also surprised how it is getting quotes.

Comment: well it doesn't need qoutes, and if the others don't have them, again, i think you have "more than meets the eye". log `escape(key)` and look for surprises...

Comment: I know quotes are unwanted and causing problem, but its getting added to the key without my knowledge because my code is generic for creating associative array with dynamic keys.

Comment: if you open the csv file in a text editor, what do you see in the last column?    if you change the order of the columns, will the last one be inaccessible as well? or it will still be the validity column? please post a csv line (after  you open it in a text editor)

Comment: If I interchange the column then which ever will be the last column was getting affected. I found the issue and solution of it too.

Comment: so please add your answer to this post to help future develolpers that will may encounter this issue